# Tips with fread

Tags: c, arrays, file, bit

I start to learn C but I already have some problem with the `fread();` function :

I have a file which I need to read it every 4bytes in a loop (like this) :

```
#define defined "\x02\xA1\xC0\xD1" // given by other student

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
  if(!fd){ return -1; }

  // get the size of our file
  fseek(f,0,SEEK_END);

  int len = ftell(f);
  fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);
  char* file = malloc(len);
  fread(file,len,1,f);

  fclose(f); // useless here apparently ?
  
  for(int x=0; x<len; x+=4){
    if(memcmp(file+x,defined,4)==0) { // compare every 4bytes until find the defined in the file
      printf("%p",x);
  }
  return(0);
}
```

I already read the MAN but I'm not sure about what I'm doing :-/

Thanks

Comment: Two issues you should clarify: (1) where are `file` and `len` defined? (2) You read the entire contents of `f` into the `file` buffer, then **fclose(f)** - what do you think subsequent attempts at reading from `f` will achieve?

Comment: fixed, and it means that I should not close the file right now ? & does the `fread(file,4,1,f);` is correct to read every 4bits ?

Comment: Note that `fread(file, 4, 1,f)` will read 4 bytes, not 4 bits.  There is no way in C to read units smaller than 1 byte from a file.

Comment: oh yes, I did a mistyped sorry, so I assume this is correct so !

Comment: You read the whole file into a `char *` variable (a memory buffer) called `file`...after you do that, the `f` file pointer is at the end again.  So even if you don't close the file at line 13, you still won't be able to `fread` anything unless you rewind again.  As a practical matter, you already have the whole file contents in memory; it would be really easy just to look at that buffer!

Comment: I barely understand but in this case, what am I supposed to use instead of `fread()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Seeking to the end of a file to get its length should be avoided whenever possible because it makes your program impossible to use with piped input.

Rather, consider reading in chunks of many 4-byte objects per call. This decreases read overhead and allows use of pipes. `fread` will tell you when it reaches end of input by returning fewer items than requested.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
  if (!f) return -1;
  const int chunk_size = 1000;
  uint32_t buf[chunk_size]; // a chunk of data read from the input in one fread()
  size_t n_read;
  do {
    n_read = fread(buf, sizeof buf[0], chunk_size, f);  // reads a chunk of ints
    for (int i = 0; i < n_read; ++i) printf("%u\n", buf[i]); // prints what was read
  } while (n_read == chunk_size); // stops when end of input is reached
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for taking your time to answer :-) sadly what you've wrote didn't work as expected and this program isn't destined to receive piped input either :-/

Comment: @AsunaYuuki "Didn't work" isn't helpful. The program does exactly what you described in the question except that it prints the values as decimal integers. The `%p` you specified prints pointers. That's not valid if you have a machine where pointers are 64 bits, which is usually true these days.

Comment: indeed, they are

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making your code more complex than it need be for the given specification.  Certainly, after your `fclose(f)`, you cannot expect anything useful from `fread(file, 4, 1, f)` — if you'd checked the return value, it would have been 0 indicating failure.

Here's a simplified version of your code.  If checks that a file name was passed; it reports if it can't open the file for reading.  It then reads 4 bytes at a time into an array, and uses `printf()` to format the offset and the data.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (!fp)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s for reading\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }

    unsigned char data[4];
    size_t offset;
    for (offset = 0; fread(data, sizeof(data), 1, fp) == 1; offset += sizeof(data))
    {
        printf("0x%.4zX: 0x%.2X%.2X%.2X%.2X\n", offset, data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]);
    }
    printf("0x%.4zX\n", offset);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled from `fread53.c` into program `fread53`, and run on its own executable, it produces:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     fread53.c -o fread53 
$ fread53 fread53
0x0000: 0xCFFAEDFE
0x0004: 0x07000001
0x0008: 0x03000080
0x000C: 0x02000000
0x0010: 0x11000000
0x0014: 0x98050000
0x0018: 0x85002000
0x001C: 0x00000000
0x0020: 0x19000000
0x0024: 0x48000000
…
0x32AC: 0x34737476
0x32B0: 0x74343276
0x32B4: 0x30303030
0x32B8: 0x30676E2F
0x32BC: 0x542F2F63
0x32C0: 0x634D3464
0x32C4: 0x6651542E
0x32C8: 0x6F005F6D
0x32CC: 0x61696E00
0x32D0
$
```

The testing was done on a Mac running macOS Catalina 10.15.2 with GCC 9.2.0 and XCode 11.3.1.

Comment: thanks for taking your time to get your code working ! I updated the post with something else just before I saw you comment, does something change with what you wrote or not ?

Comment: If you want to compare each 4-byte sequence with a specific pattern and print the offset or address where it occurs, you have to modify the body of the loop in my code to make the comparison and only do the printing if the bytes in `data` match the search string.  It's a straightforward change to make.  It will only find the pattern when it starts at a 4-byte boundary (0, 4, 8, 12, …) in the file.